# Show runtime of a query on monetdb

Tags: monetdb

I am testing monetdb for a colunmnar storage.

I already installed and run the server
but, when I connect to the client and run a query, the response does not show the time to execute the query.
I am connecting as:

> mclient -u monetdb -d voc

I already tried to connect with interactive like:

> mclient -u monetdb -d voc -i

Output example:

```
sql>select count(*) from voc.regions;
+---------+
| L3      |
+=========+
| 5570699 |
+---------+
1 tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the latest version MonetDB-Mar18 you have good control over the performance timers, which includes parsing, optimization, and runtime at server. See mclient --help.

Answer (score 2):

As mkersten mentioned, I would read through the options of the [`mclient`](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/mclient-man-page) utility first.

To get server and client timing measurements I used `--timer=performance` option when starting `mclient`.

Inside `mclient` I would then disable the result output by setting `\f trash` to ignore the results when measuring only.

Prepend [`trace`](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Trace) to your query and you get your results like this:

```
sql>\f trash
sql>trace select count(*) from categories;
sql:0.000 opt:0.266 run:1.713 clk:5.244 ms
sql:0.000 opt:0.266 run:2.002 clk:5.309 ms
```

The first of the two lines shows you the server timings, the second one the overall timing including passing the results back to the client.